# Endomorphism of a Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $C$ be a curve of genus $g$ defined over the finite field $k=\mathbb{F}_q$. Set $A=J(C)$ the jacobian of $C$, then $A$ is an abelian variety defined over $k$ of dimension $g$.

The algebra $End_k(A)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is semisimple with center $K=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, where $\pi$ represents the Frobenius endomorphism. $End_k(A)\cap K$ is an order in $K$, say $\mathcal{O}$.

We fix $h(X)\in\mathbb{Q}(X)$ such that $h(\pi)\in \mathcal{O}_K$ is an algebraic integer.

Do you know which informations on $C$ allow us to know if $h(\pi)$ lies or not in $\mathcal{O}$ (i.e. $h(\pi)$ is an endomorphism of $A$)?